# PIL creating thumbnail error (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography

I'm coding a stenography code, but my problem is the size of the image that I want to Hide on another image. 
Because if the image container is smaller than the image to hide that's return an error of out of index.

So I find a solution, it's to create a thumbnail of the image to hide if the size is bigger than the image container.

Here is the code (return the error in the title):

```py
    global filepath,filepath2
    im_pass = PIL.Image.open(filepath)
    im_cont = PIL.Image.open(filepath2)
    width_x, height_y = im_pass.size #(x,y)
    width_x2, height_y2 = im_cont.size #(x,y)
    if width_x > width_x2 or height_y > height_y2:
        if width_x2 > height_y2:
            max_size = width_x2
            min_size = height_y2
        elif height_y2 > width_x2:
            max_size = height_y2
            min_size = width_x2
        width_x, height_y = int(min_size//1.5), int(min_size//1.5)
        im_pass.thumbnail(width_x,height_y)
```

```py
  File ".\Projet_final.py", line 21, in Stega
    im_pass.thumbnail(width_x,height_y)
  File "C:\Users\Naylor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2119, in thumbnail
    if x > size[0]:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

So what I'm expecting is to create the thumbnail and to Hide it into the container image (that part already work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails) ([reference](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail)), `thumbnail` expects the size to be defined in a tuple of `(width, height)`, and not two separate parameters.

```
global filepath,filepath2
    im_pass = PIL.Image.open(filepath)
    im_cont = PIL.Image.open(filepath2)
    width_x, height_y = im_pass.size #(x,y)
    width_x2, height_y2 = im_cont.size #(x,y)
    if width_x > width_x2 or height_y > height_y2:
        if width_x2 > height_y2:
            max_size = width_x2
            min_size = height_y2
        elif height_y2 > width_x2:
            max_size = height_y2
            min_size = width_x2
        width_x, height_y = int(min_size//1.5), int(min_size//1.5)
        im_pass.thumbnail((width_x,height_y))
```

Comment: @Rzdhop Happens to the best of us, and I wish that was a joke heh ^^